# Total variation inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

In the article from Lugosi and Devroye 1999 about testability of densities (page 13) I've stumbled upon this inequality:
$$
V(f) \leq C(f)s(f)
$$
where $f$ is a Lipschitz$(1)$ density with Lipschitz constant $C(f)<\infty$ and support $s(f)$. How can this be derived? Also why is this true?
$$
\int \sqrt{f} \leq \sqrt{s(f)\int f} = \sqrt{s(f)}
$$
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Two different questions (probably homework, no (probability) or (statistics) in them). Re the first one: write down the definition of V(f) as a supremum over partitions.

Comment: @Did This is an estimate from [page 13 of this paper](http://repositori.upf.edu/bitstream/handle/10230/1024/375.pdf). To Rodel: [providing such context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) would likely avoid  the question being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, $V(f) = \sup_{P \in \mathcal{P(f)}} \sum_{i=0}|f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)| \leq \sup_{P \in \mathcal{P(f)}} \sum_{i=0}C(f)|x_{i+1} - x_i| = C(f)\sum_{i=0}(x_{i+1}-x_i) = C(f)S(f).$

For the second, use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\int_{s(f)} \sqrt{f} \leq (\int_{s(f)} \sqrt{f}^2)^{1/2}(\int_{s(f)} 1)^{1/2} = \sqrt{s(f)}$ since $\int f = 1$ as $f$ is a density function.